# Avoid getting "glued" words with R webscraping

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

When I use both of the two following blocks of code code, I get "glued" words, and by that i mean words that are not not separated by a space but they should, and this is a problem. In the original HTML, it seem like they're separated by a `<b>` and i'm not beeing able to handle this. The two blocks do the same thing by different ways.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
# Block 1---------
url <- "https://www.letras.mus.br/red-hot-chili-peppers/32739/"
u <- readLines(url)
h <- htmlTreeParse(file=u,  
               asText=TRUE, 
               useInternalNodes = TRUE, 
               encoding = "utf-8")

song <- getNodeSet(doc=h, path="//article", fun=xmlValue)

# Block 2---------
u <- "https://www.letras.mus.br/red-hot-chili-peppers/32739/"
h <- htmlParse(getURL(u))
song <- xpathSApply(h, path = "//article", fun = xmlValue)
```

Which returns something like:

[1] "Sometimes I feelLike I don't have a **partnerSometimes** I **feelLike** my only friendIs the city I live **inThe** city of **angelsLonely** as I amTogether we cryI drive on her streets'Cause she's my companionI walk through her hills'Cause she knows who I amShe sees my good **deedsAnd** she kisses me windyI never **worryNow** that is a lieI don't ever wanna **feelLike** I did that dayBut take me to the place I loveTake me all the wayIt's hard to **believeThat** there's nobody out thereIt's hard to believeThat I'm all aloneAt...

Comment: A quick and dirty fix would be to put `u <- gsub("<br/>"," ",as.character(u))` after the `u <- readLines(url)` line. It will replace every <br/> with a space. Alternatively you could also use `u <- gsub("<br/>","\n",as.character(u))` if you wanted to keep it as a line break instead of a space.

Comment: @MattJewett i had something like that in mind also. anyway, if its dirty or not, it worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve words with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.letras.mus.br/red-hot-chili-peppers/32739/")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 
page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

list_Text_Song <- list()

for(i in 1 : 30)
{
  print(i)
  web_Obj <- tryCatch(remDr$findElement("xpath", paste0("//*[@id='js-lyric-cnt']/article/div[2]/div[2]/p[", i, "]")), error = function(e) NA)
  list_Text_Song[[i]] <- tryCatch(web_Obj$getElementText(), error = function(e) NA)
}

list_Text_Song <- unlist(list_Text_Song)
list_Text_Song <- list_Text_Song[!is.na(list_Text_Song)]
```

The words are not glued with this approach.